# No module named pyGTK - Possible PYTHONPATH Error?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I'm trying to run a program called Nicotine+ on my Mac which is running 10.8.5. Nicotine+ requires GTK2, PyGTK2 and Python to run. I believe I have all of these installed via Macports. - List of installed ports here - http://pastebin.com/nwmrpp2Y

When I try to run Nicotine+ I get this message:

```
'/Users/******/Downloads/nicotine+-1.2.16', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',   
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages'] Exception: No module named pygtk
```

If I run Python and type import pygtk I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygtk
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running it with the system Python, and not the macports version which is installed in `/usr/local/bin/`.

You can either add this path in your shell `export PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH` or adjust the startup script for nicotine to use the macports version of Python.